# setting property by reflection

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm trying to set UpperTitle populating Title.ToUpper every time Title set accessor is hit.

```
public string Title 
{
   get { return Title; }
   set
       {
          Title = value;
          UpperTitle = Title.ToUpper();
       }
}
public string UpperTitle { get; protected set; }
```

This code compiles but I'm not sure is it ok, cause I'm getting mapping exception

```
problem to set property by reflection
```

Comment: mark mapped properties with `virtual` keyword

Comment: not sure why there is a property for just get the upper case of another property :)

Comment: @Damith cause I want to add db index on that property for future checks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `get` you are calling the `get` (infinite loop) again! So change your code like this:

```
private string _title;

public string Title 
{
   get { return _title; }
   set
   {
      _title= value;
      UpperTitle = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_title)? string.Empty : _title.ToUpper();
   }
}

public string UpperTitle { get; protected set; }
```

Comment: Just a suggestion to add a null check in there before doing the ToUpper.